# Gson How to skip the field when the exception “java.lang.IllegalStateException” occurred？

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, okhttp

**Model**

```
public class Result<T> {
    private String code;
    private String msg;
    private T data;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

`Api` result

Success(data maybe is a string,list and so on)

```
{
    "code":200,
    "msg":"success",
    "data":{
               "name":"zhangsan",
                "age":18
             }
}
```

Failure

```
{
    "code":401,
    "msg":"success",
    "data":[]
}
```

or

```
{
    "code":401,
    "msg":"success",
    "data":""
}
```

When the result is Failure the The exception occurred

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 23 path $.data
```

I just want to skip the field "data" because it is unused when the failure result,
And keep the other fields. not an exception

Can use TypeAdapterFactory TypeAdapter to skip data?How can I do???

Comment: Any library you are using for API calling? (Like `Retrofit`)

Comment: @Prathamesh Toradmal yes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your model. That's right, it's true.

```
public class JsonData{

    @SerializedName("code")
    private Long mCode;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private Data mData;
    @SerializedName("msg")
    private String mMsg;

    public Long getCode() {
        return mCode;
    }

    public void setCode(Long code) {
        mCode = code;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return mData;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return mMsg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        mMsg = msg;
    }

}


public class Data {

    @SerializedName("age")
    private Long mAge;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String mName;

    public Long getAge() {
        return mAge;
    }

    public void setAge(Long age) {
        mAge = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: data maybe is a string,list and so on

Comment: This is trouble with backend. 
If you use a retrofit, you can override jsonconvertor. And it will be correct if you have only an array in the data field. And in this case, treat 3 cases quite difficult.

Comment: Can use TypeAdapterFactory TypeAdapter to skip data?

Comment: You can try, but it's best to try to fix it on the server. Should look like this: data: [ ]

Answer (score 0):

You can apply check on `code`:

```
If (code == 200){
    // success logic
}
else if(code == 401){
    // failure logic
}
```

Otherwise if you are using `Retrofit` library it should go to `success` and `failure` block automatically. You don't need to take care of that. Use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) link to create your Pojo class from the `Response` you get from server.

Comment: Yes,I know.But I want to know gson can do that?

Comment: Yes, then you have to manually handle `data` part. If code is 401 then again check there is it contains array, string or object

Comment: Can use TypeAdapterFactory TypeAdapter to skip data?